# FB.Event.subscribe auth.statusChange not firing in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, events

In my service:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : "",
    xfbml      : false
    version    : 'v2.0',
    status     : true 
  });
};
```

In My controller:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      //Continue
    }else{
      console.log("FB not connected")
     }
});

FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
          //Continue
        } else {
          // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
          console.log("not logged in");
        }
})
```

I do not see any of console logs messages. infact the auth.statuschange is not getting fired. Please guide me in the correct direction.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather put this as a comment, but I can't because of reputation.
Quick question: Are you already logged in on facebook? Because then you would log nothing.